# how to constrain 2 matrix such that they don't cancel out in optimization

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Given a simple generic optimization problem

> argmin y = (A+B)x + g(x) + epsilon

Let's say we want to fix the matrix A, and allow for free-form optimization on B. What kind of regularization or constraints can we simply impose on B in such way that elements of B will not cancel out the elements of the fixed matrix A?

Edit: Let us also further assume that matrix A is generally sparse, i.e. we want to include some prior knowledge of (A+B) in this problem by providing the known matrix A. My concern is that in many cases, some elements of A will be canceled out by B.

Edit2: Maybe we can even relax this constraint further. We do not want to completely prevent B from canceling out A, but simply want to encourage B to not do so.

Comment: So every $B_{ij}$ has to be far away from the corresponding $-A_{ij}$? Isn't that already a set of constraints? Or what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I guess that is in the same vein of what I am asking for. Maybe to maximize the distance between A and B we just have to make sure to include a maximization on alpha*|cov(A+B)|? I guess my question is slightly more detailed. Like what general formulations people generally use for this kind of problem :)

Comment: It's not really clear *why* you want to prevent $B$ from cancelling out elements of $A$. Since you say $A$ is sparse, is the idea that you know what those entries of the matrix $A+B$ should be, and you don't want $B$ to move away from that? In that case you could perform the optimization only over the other entries of $B$, the ones where $A$ is zero.

Comment: Thanks for the response. To elaborate more on that. Let say I only know those elements in A exists but not entirely certain about their magnitude, in that case, I want to simply set those elements in A to 1 and let B be a linear modifier for such elements except for the case where B will cancel out A due to our prior knowledge. B also try to optimize for other relation that is not know, thus free-form optimization on B.